# At SwiftUI how do you assign different actions if buttons are created in a loop

Tags: swiftui

How can you assign different actions if you are creating buttons in a loop when using SwiftUI.

I was using sender tag while using UIView.

At following code, every buttons calls the same function as usual.
How can I make them call different action in case we are using loops to create buttons.

```
var buttonNames = ["OK", "NOPE"]

var body: some View {

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(buttonNames.count)
    
    ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyHStack {
            ForEach(0..<buttonNames.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Button(buttonNames[index]) {
                 buttonTouched()
             }.frame(width: width)
              .background(Color.gray)
                               
                       }
        
         }
         
         .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 45, alignment: .center)
         .foregroundColor(.white)
         .background(Color.gray)
         
            
    
    
}
    .position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 45)
   
}
```

Comment: Make a button model that has a variable for the label and a variable for the action.

Answer (score 0):

```
After the comment I did it like this and it makes the trick.


var buttonNames = ["OK", "NOPE"]
@State var touchedButton = 0



func buttonTouched(){
    print("Button tapped! \(touchedButton)")
    
}


var body: some View {

let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(buttonNames.count)

        ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {

          LazyHStack {

            ForEach(0..<buttonNames.count, id: \.self) {
                index in
             
                Button(action:{
                     
                    touchedButton = index
                    buttonTouched()
                        
                        }
                ){
                   
                    Text(buttonNames[index])
                    
                    
                }
                .frame(width: width)
                
            }
            
        }
        
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 45, alignment: .center)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.gray)
        
        
        
        
    } .position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 45)


   }
```